# python pass self to referenced function

Tags: python

I have a function reference that is being called by an object. What I'd like is for that object to pass itself as a parameter to the function as it would normally do for its own functions.

IE I would like to use self.myFoo() instead of self.myFoo(self) in the following sample

Code Sample:

```
def foo(self):
    print(self.toString())

class Node:
    def __init__(self, myFoo):
        self.myFoo = myFoo

    def run(self):
        self.myFoo()

    def toString(self):
        return "Hello World"

n = Node(foo)
n.run()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `self.myFoo(self)`?

Comment: Nothing, mostly just curious as to why self.myFoo() doesn't work; also if I can make it work

Comment: The `self` in `def foo(self)` is misleading. I don't think that code runs.

Comment: it won't, you have to replace self.myFoo() with self.myFoo(self) for it to run

Comment: @vttran: The positional argument name `self` works, but you're right that it's misleading and not ideal. Similarly, you can rename a method's first argument to whatever you want, but 'self' is pretty standard.

Comment: @Alter: `self.myFoo()` doesn't work because you need to pass in an argument to fulfill the positional argument requirement. Your use of `self` as the argument for `foo` is misleading you, try changing the identifier to `obj` or `potato`.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work. What I'm hoping for is some way to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you assigned myFoo to an unbound function and are calling it as though it were bound. If you want to be able to use `self.myFoo()` you will need to curry the object into the first arg yourself.

```
from functools import partial

def foo(self):
    print(self.toString())

class Node:
    def __init__(self, myFoo):
        self.myFoo = partial(myFoo, self)

    def run(self):
        self.myFoo()

    def toString(self):
        return "Hello World"

n = Node(foo)
n.run()
```

Alternatively you could use

```
self.myFoo = types.MethodType(myFoo, self)
```

in your `__init__(self, myFoo)` method, but using partial is more commonly done, and more versatile since you can use it to curry arguments for any sort of function, not just methods.

Comment: Good one, forgot about `partial`.

Comment: Did not know that you can do that either. Neato! This is just gave me a GEB Déjà vu.

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object) looks like what you are looking for. To bound a method to an object (but not its class) at runtime you can do:

```
import types
n.foo = types.MethodType(foo, n)
```

Comment: kudoos for this one, If i could select two answers I would accept yours too

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a simple function. To make it callable via `self.myFoo()` you can attach it to the class - not the object. Even `Node.myFoo` is still an unbound function you can call it via `self.myFoo()` within your class.

```
def __init__(self, myFoo):
    Node.myFoo = myFoo
```